# Is it possible to make active/responsive checkbox in Jasper Studion?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

so my question is about active/responsive checkboxes. Is it possible to make it? For example user prints out the report in .pdf and with his mouse can he check the checkbox?  Has anyone tried to do it or has heard of it?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out how to do it.

```
<reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="25" height="25">
  <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.field.type" value="Check"/>
  <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.field.check.type" value="Square"/>
  <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.field.checked" value="true"/>
</reportElement>
```

I just changed it to radio buttons.

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/forms/index.html